# Multiplicar un echo de PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

Sigo con la tabla de filtrados por divs.
Pues bien, ahora estoy haciendo un SELECT que tiene dos opciones "PVP con IVA" "PVP sin IVA".

En el ciclo WILE salen todos los resultados dependiendo de otros selects y sacados de una BD. Lo que necesito saber es como hacer para que cuando le den al select de pvp con iva le sume el IVA al precio de la BD, sin necesidad de actualizar cambie el resultado en el echo.

Este es la fila donde regresa el echo:

```
<div id="pvp"><p style="color: #f67b48;"><?php echo $res['total']; ?>€</p></div>
```

Aquí es donde hago las diferentes consultas para los otros selects y luego por AJAX me cambia el contenido de DIV completo con una ID.

```
$orden =$_POST['ordenar'];
$tip =$_POST['tipo'];
$id =$_POST['ID'];

$result = null;

if($_POST['tipo'] == 0){
   $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT productos.id, productos.producto, productos.imagen, productos.alias, posibles.idproducto, posibles.tipo, posibles.entrada, posibles.mensualidad, posibles.final, posibles.total FROM productos, posibles WHERE productos.id = posibles.idproducto AND posibles.idproducto = $id ORDER BY posibles.total $orden");
}else{
   $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT productos.id, productos.producto, productos.imagen, productos.alias, posibles.idproducto, posibles.tipo, posibles.entrada, posibles.mensualidad, posibles.final, posibles.total FROM productos, posibles WHERE productos.id = posibles.idproducto AND posibles.idproducto = $id AND posibles.tipo = $tip ORDER BY posibles.total $orden");
        }
   mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
   while($res = $results->fetch_array()) {
```

Aqui el resultado del while que luego se imprime en el HTML:

```
<div class="col-12 planos">
 <div class="row planos2">
   <div class="col-1"><img src="images/<?php echo $res['imagen']; ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid"></div>
   <div class="col-2 plan4 corrijepad">
       <h4><?php
         if ($res['tipo'] == 1) echo "Alquiler";
         if ($res['tipo'] == 2) echo "Comprar";
         if ($res['tipo'] == 3) echo "Explotación compartida";
       ?></h4></p>
   <p><?php echo $res['producto']; ?> <span><?php echo $res['alias']; ?></span></p>
   </div>                
   <div class="col-2 plan6 center">
      <h4>ENTRADA</h4>
      <p><?php echo $res['entrada']; ?>€</p>
   </div>
      <div class="col-2 plan6 center" style="padding: 0px;">
      <h4>CUOTA</h4>
      <p><?php echo $res['mensualidad']; ?><span>€/mes (36)</span></p>
       </div>
      <div class="col-2 plan6 center" style="padding: 0px;">
         <h4>FINAL</h4>
         <p><?php echo $res['final']; ?>€</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 plan6 center" style="padding: 0px;">
         <h4>TOTAL</h4>
         <p style="color: #f67b48;"><?php echo $res['total']; ?>€</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 pull-right" style="padding: 0px;">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary bonton-quiero ">Comprar</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary bonton-quiero2 ">Detalles</button>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>    
 <?php } ?>
```

Y por ultimo el AJAX que eta en la pagina principal:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
    $("#ordenar, #tipo, #ID").on("change", function(e){
      var ordenar ="";
      var tipo ="";
      var id ="";

        if ($("#ordenar").val() !=null){
          ordenar = $("#ordenar").val();
        }
        if ($("#tipo").val() !=null){
          tipo = $("#tipo").val();
        }
        if ($("#ID").val() !=null){
          ID = $("#ID").val();
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "filtros.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "html",
            data: {
            'ordenar': ordenar,
            'tipo': tipo,
            'ID': ID,
            },
            beforeSend: function(){
              $("#res").html("<div class='ui active inline loader'></div>")
            },
            success: function (resultado){
              $("#res").html(resultado);
            }
    });
});

    });
</script>
```

Aquí esta el fomulario que gestiona todo:

```
<form class="ui form" method="post">
  <div class="field">
    <select class="ui fluid dropdown" id="tipo" name="tipo">            
        <?php 
         $result_1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tipos " ); 
            echo "<option value='0'>Todos</option>";
            while ($row_1 = $result_1->fetch_array()) 
           {                          
          if ($row_1['id'] ==$_GET['necesito']) 
          {   echo "<option value='".$row_1['id']."' selected>".$row_1['tipo']."</option>";} 
          else{    
          echo "<option value='".$row_1['id']."'>".$row_1['tipo']."</option>";
         } 
         }  
         ?>
         </select>
    </div></div>

            <div class="col-3">
              <h4 class="h4stn">ORDENAR POR PRECIO</h4>

                <div class="field">
                  <select class="ui fluid dropdown" id="ordenar" name="ordenar">
                    <option value="">Elige el orden</option>
                    <option value="ASC">Más barato primero</option>
                    <option value="DESC">Más caro primero</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-3">
              <h4 class="h4stn">OPCIONES</h4>

                <div class="field">
                  <select class="ui fluid dropdown" id="pvp" name="pvp">
                    <option value="">¿Como quieres ver los precios?</option>
                    <option value="si">PVP con iva</option>
                    <option value="no">PVP con sin iva</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="ID" id="ID" value="<?php echo $res['id']; ?>">

            <div class="col-3">
              <h4 class="h4stn">MODELOS</h4>

                <div class="field">
                  <select class="ui fluid dropdown" id="productos" name="productos" onchange="javascript:handleSelect(this)">
                        <option value="">Elige el modelo</option>
                    <?php
                      //var_dump($_GET);
                      $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE estado = 1");
                      mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
                      while($res = $results->fetch_array()) {
                      ?>
                        <option value="equipos.php?ID=<?php echo $res['id']; ?>"><?php echo $res['producto']; ?> <small><?php echo $res['alias']; ?></small></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                  </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Puedes hacerlo en el mismo SQL o en PHP, si compartes el código podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Hola! era por no llenar mucho el mensaje, pero ahora comparto lo que tengo hasta ahora

Comment: Ya he puesto todo el código, gracias!

Comment: Lo siento, por  mucho que miro tu código y trato de entender lo que preguntas, no veo por ningún sitio ningún campo del porcentaje del IVA que debe aplicarse, ni donde se selecciona la opción de verlo con IVA o sin él.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, te he dejado el formulario donde están los selects! Faltaria todo lo demás porque no se muy bien como lo tengo que hacer, imagino que el select de PVP que tiene que ser el que maneje los cambios de precio, tendra que realizar un ajax imagino...